# Arduino Leonardo clone voltage question

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I'm planning my first Arduino project which involves a MPU-6050 accelerometer(3.3V) and a RGB led(5V). I've found this [Arduino Clone](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01HAZ2M8A/) but i'm not sure if it has 3.3V and 5V outputs that I can use. The pins do exist on the original Leonardo board but i'm not sure if the clone contains them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has a 5V pin (Vcc) but no 3.3V. Also the 5V pin can't provide more than a few hundred mA.

Better specifications are here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. If I find a 5V accelerometer would I be able to connect it + the led to the same 5V pin?

Comment: Yep. Note that a 5v accelerometer will probably be a 3.3v one with built in 3.3v regulator, so you need to take the same precautions as a 3.3v one.

Comment: What kind of procautions do you mean? Could you maybe give me term to google to send me down the right path?

Comment: Logic level shifting. Interfacing a 5v Arduino to a 3.3v device. If the accelerometer is I2C include that in your search too.